# Issues separating a sublist

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, filter

I've been given a task to sort which, out of a list of items, which ones
are not contained in the other list.

In this case it's NI numbers that do not possess a bank account.

The types are as follows:

```
    type NI = Int
    type Age = Int
    type Balance = Int
    type Person = (NI, Age, Balance)
    type Bank = [Person]
    type Market = [Bank]
    type Pop = [NI]
```

The bankFree function is as follows:

```
    bankFree :: Pop -> Market -> Pop
    bankFree a b = filter (map op3 b) a
        where 
            op3 [(x, y, z)] = x
```

I'm completely stumped on where I go from here. I know that I will have to work on the Pop list in order to remove the elements from the map operation from that list. I've tried to fit in notElem and perform a bunch of other different tests but to no use.

Would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: make sure your `op3` is doing what you expect (what is its type? will it handle all possible inputs?). are you familiar with concept like intersection, union, etc. from [set theory](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/official/ch02s08s02.html)? you might find that another data structure like like [Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Map.html) or Data.Set may be better suited and already provide the functions you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick of programming is to figure out how to split a complex problem into simpler ones. It may be easier to get this intuition if you practice the other way around - build solutions to complex problems from solutions to simple problems. That way you can feel which way the problems are simplified most effectively.

This problem is easy to decompose. Let's start with a simplest problem, and extend upwards:

- can you solve this problem for one NI and one Person? This is one function
- can you extend this solution for one NI and many Persons (one Bank)? This is another function - possibly using the previous one
- can you extend this solution for one NI and many Banks (one Market)? Yet another function - possibly using the previous one
- can you apply this solution to all NIs (one Pop)? One more function - possibly using the previous one

That's it.

Comment: That's it. I simply broke it down and constructed a function which searches each bank and returns a Bool. From that I simply filtered the Market list and got my answer. Thanks a lot :) Can't believe I forgot basic programming haha